# How to make turtles / agents go faster or slower when being on a certain patch?

Tags: performance, netlogo, patch, agent

I have to make turtles go faster when being on a green patch, and when they are on a blue patch the speed should go down. I added part of the code that I tried, but it doesn't work. Could someone please help me?
Thanks in advance!!

```
turtles-own [speed]

to go                                                                                   
ask turtles [

left 60                                                                             
right random 60                                                                     
forward 1                                                                                                                 

  

if any? neighbors with [pcolor = green]
    [
      set speed speed + 1
       ]

    
if any? neighbors with [pcolor = blue]
    [
      set speed speed + 0.1
        ]

 ]

reset-ticks
```

Comment: Should the turtle change speed based on solely the patch it is standing on, or also the 8 surrounding patches?

Comment: @user2901351 solely the patch it is on

Comment: @user2901351 can you help me?

Comment: You seem to have accidentally removed most of the info in your question - and broken consistent text. I will undo that for you. Please make sure that the answer stays as answerable as it was when the existing answers were created. Otherwise you make them look like wild guessing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what user2901351 was getting at was that you are using `neighbors` in your example code. If you look at the [dictionary entry for neighbors](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors), you'll see that it references the 8 patches *around* the current patch. If you instead want the turtle to check the patch it's currently on, you can use the [patch-here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-here) primitive or, as a shortcut, just ask the `turtle` to check a patch-owned variable directly. Below is a toy example that shows an example of this at work- more details in the comments.

```
turtles-own [speed]

to setup 
  ca
  crt 5 [ set speed 1 ]
  ask n-of 20 patches [ 
    ifelse random-float 1 < 0.5 
    [ set pcolor green ]
    [ set pcolor blue ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go                                                                                   
  ask turtles [
    ; Since 'pcolor' is a patch variable, if the turtle queries pcolor
    ; it will check the patch's variable directly.
    if pcolor = green [ set speed speed + 0.5 ]
    if pcolor = blue [ set speed speed - 0.5 ]
    ; Make sure that the turtles are moving forward by their speed value, 
    ; rather than the hard-coded value of "1" in the example code. Also,
    ; I've included a check here so the turtles don't either stop moving
    ; or start moving backwards.
    if speed < 1 [ set speed 1 ]
    rt random-float 60 - 30
    fd speed
    show speed
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: thanks! It works!
Do you mind taking a look at the other question that I posted? :)

Comment: Shouldn't the check be `if (speed <= 0) [set speed 0]` (or `[set speed 0.1]` or something similar if turtles cannot stop)? Using `forward` with a number greater than 0 and smaller than 1 still means moving forward

Comment: @Matteo - I'm not sure I understand- I was just putting something in so that they have a base speed, I chose 1 arbitrarily (because it looks 'nice' to me in terms of turtles in the world) rather than in response to any specific component of the question.

Comment: @LukeC - Oh, ok, I thought and understood that you wanted to introduce a check which prevented turtles from stopping (i.e. preventing `speed` from getting as low as 0) and/or from going backwards (i.e. preventing `speed` from dropping below 0)